# Removing index.php from codeigniter URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, xampp

I've copied the code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

[from here...](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

and copied it in a new .htaccess file and placed it in root directory of my project (D:\xampp\htdocs\testproj).
but it's not working.
showing error 404 when accesing without index.php
help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what u need friend

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: working, thanks :) by the way the previous was not working (the official one)

Comment: Happy to hear that dont forget to give the checklist to the answer :)

Comment: i'll as soon as it permits... but can u explain the difference?